# Problem sorting list of strings - Python

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of strings:

```
cards = ['2S', '8D', '8C', '4C', 'TS', '9S', '9D', '9C', 'AC', '3D']
```

and the order in which I want to display the cards:

```
CARD_ORDER = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
```

---

**This is how I'm trying to order the list:**

```
sorted(cards, lambda x,y: CARD_ORDER.index(x[0]) >= CARD_ORDER.index(y[0]) )
```

**Unfortunately this does not seem to work....**

or more precisely the list stays exactly the same, `sorted(cards)` works fine instead.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it's

```
sorted(cards, key=lambda x: CARD_ORDER.index(x[0]))
```

`key` parameter accepts a single value, by which to sort the main iterable. You're probably trying to use `cmp` parameter which is not recommended for quite some time.

Comment: that works thanks, any explanation why the other way does not work?

Comment: @RadiantHex, because you are using `>=` which only returns `False` or `True` (`0` or `1`), whereas the [comparison function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) is expected to return `-1`, `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sorted(cards, key = lambda x: CARD_ORDER.index(x[0]) )
```